# If is it Possible for auto click

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want[image] to Auto click this button using jquery or java script. it is possible or not.**

> **ITS NOT DUPLICATE** . i am asking about the **browser PRINT button** not normal button. I know its possible to do with button auto submit based
>   on time duration. but here this button is **PRINT PREVIEW DIALOG BOX**
>   button. i want to write event for that button.

Remove the duplication mark

Comment: yea i already i look at that page but i asking about "this button is browser button "

Answer (score -1):

is your question like this?

```html
<button onclick="print();">print</button>
```

Comment: did you understand my question or not?